# Echo the_post_thumbnail in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have been trying to echo the post thumbnail for worpress using the string and the function but it doesnt work.

Here is the template i am trying to show it.

```
    if ($favorite_post_ids):
            $favorite_post_ids = array_reverse($favorite_post_ids);
            foreach ($favorite_post_ids as $post_id) {
                $p = get_post($post_id);
                echo "<li>";
                echo "<a href='".get_permalink($post_id)."' title='". $p->post_title ."'>" . $p->post_title . "</a> ";
echo '<img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail(array(55,55)).'" />';
                wpfp_remove_favorite_link($post_id);
                echo "</li>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parameter of get_the_post_thumbnail() is the post ID, not the thumbnail size

Comment: Thanks i got it working `echo "" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array(55,55), array('class' => 'fav-thumbs')) . "";`